# Can we modify a Font Awesome spin speed?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, font-awesome

I have a spinning gear on my website displayed with this code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<i class = "fa fa-cog fa-5x fa-spin"></i>
```

Personally, I think that the speed of the gear is too fast. Can I modify it with CSS?

Comment: Just keep the font awesome icon and add your own class to it instead of `fa-spin`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, you can. Replace the `.fa-spin` class on the icon with a new class using your own animation rule:

```css
.slow-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 6s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 6s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<i class = "fa fa-cog fa-5x slow-spin"></i>
```

### Longer answer

If you look at the [`Font Awesome CSS file`](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css), you'll see this rule for spinning animation:

```
.fa-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

The rule for the `.fa-spin` class refers to the `fa-spin` keyframes:

```
@keyframes fa-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

You can use the same keyframes in a different class. For example, you can write the following rule for a class called `.slow-spin`:

```
.slow-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 6s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 6s infinite linear;
}
```

Now you can rotate HTML elements at the speed of your choosing. Instead of applying the class `.fa-spin` to an element, apply the `.slow-spin` class:

```
<i class = "fa fa-cog fa-5x slow-spin"></i>
```

Comment: It seems like the animation is now called `a`. If this answer is not working, I would recommend checking the name in the inspector.

Comment: This worked for me, although my situation is a bit different.  I used the fa-spin code to create my own CSS class.  The only difference is, I'm using Font Awesome react components instead of the traditional way of implementing Font Awesome in a web application.

Answer (score 25):

Not necessary to use an own animation or class definition. The speed of any css animation can control by the [animation-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration) css property. Simply use:

```
.fa-spin {
  animation-duration: 3s; // or something else
}
```

As higher the value the lower the animation speed.

Comment: Informative though the chosen answer is, this is the best for its conciseness and expressiveness 

Comment: This is a good answer only if you want all of the icons on your page to take on the new speed. If you want a specific icon to have a different speed, then the other answer that shows how to create your own class is better.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the Michael Laszlo's answer. This is what I use to make it faster for fa-refresh as the fa-spin by default is very slow.

```
.fa-spin {
 -webkit-animation: fa-spin 0.75s infinite linear !important;
 animation: fa-spin 0.75s infinite linear !important;
}
```

I use !important so that I control the specificity :)